# Linq left join with group join

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have set of Users and Visits. (So user do visits)

Visit have User navigation property.

I need to find the users who don't visit.

I can do this by finding the users who visit, finding all of the users then taking the difference.

I was trying to find a solution which is faster.

This is what I have right now:

```
  var users = _db.Users.AsNoTracking().Include(c => c.City).Where(x => x.City.Id == city);

  var groupedUsers = _db.Visits.AsNoTracking().Include(c => c.City).Include(a=>a.VisitedBy).Where(x => x.City.Id == city).GroupBy(x => x.VisitedBy).Select(group => new { VisitedBy = group.Key, Count = group.Count() });

  var visitingUsers = groupedUsers.Select(user => user.VisitedBy);

  var dif = users.Except(visitingUsers);
```

However I was trying GroupJoin as below:

```
   var results = _db.Users.Include(c => c.City).Where(c => c.City.Id == city).
            GroupJoin(_db.Visits.Include(c => c.City).Include(u => u.VisitedBy), u => u.Id, v => v.VisitedBy.Id, (u, v) => new { User = u , Visits = v })
            .Select(o=>o.User);
```

But this gives me all of the Users, I want the users who don't exist in the Visit set.

Any help?

Comment: A null check in combination with a left join usually accomplishes what you're attempting...

Comment: where ? Not sure where i should put the null check.

Comment: In SQL we do: `SELECT ... FROM a LEFT JOIN b ON (a.X = b.X) WHERE b.X IS NULL`. Is there no comparable Linq way of doing that?

Comment: Should both users and visits be filtered by `city`?

Comment: Yes, for specific city but assume it is not there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be able to avoid the correlated sub-query in the other answer by actually doing the left join with null check. Here's a quick example:

```
var A = new [] { new Foo { Bar = 1 }, new Foo { Bar = 2 }};
var B = new [] { new Foo { Bar = 2 }};

var C = from x in A
        join y in B on x.Bar equals y.Bar into z
        from y in z.DefaultIfEmpty()
        where y == null
        select x;
```

Check the emitted SQL...

Comment: subquery shouldn't be any slower than the join, but yea this would get rid of it.

Comment: @Cory, yeah probably doesn't matter for a small number of records, but my SQL best practices always tell me to perfer joins over subqueries if you can make no assumption about how the data is indexed.

Comment: To make this faster what should i index?

Comment: That's difficult to say without firing up the query analyzer and comparing execution plans...

Comment: It is my SQL best practices that foreign-keys should be indexed, i.e. `VisitedById` meaning my sub-query should be near enough as fast as a join and faster if there were multiple visits for some users.

Comment: @Luke, yup, I would normally expect foreign keys to be indexed. There's nothing wrong with your answer, just a matter of preference I suppose.

Answer (score 3):

I am not too sure if the city filtering is what you are after however the following should achieve what you desire:

```
var visitsToCity = _db.Visits.Where(v => v.City.Id == city);
var usersOfCity = _db.Users.Where(u => u.City.Id == city);

var nonVisitingUsers = usersOfCity.Where(u => !visitsToCity.Any(v => v.VisitedBy == u));
```

The last `Where` combined with the `Any` should result in a SQL statement like:

```
SELECT * FROM Users u WHERE u.CityId = @p0 AND 
    NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Visits v WHERE v.CityId = @p0 AND
                  v.VisitedById = u.Id)
```

Where `@p0` will be supplied with the value of `city`.